# nacido, *nato, *nado in ABBYY dictionary - what it means?

Tags: conjugación

https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/es-ru/nacer

I see

`nacido, *nato, *nado`

What the words with asterisk `*nato, *nado` mean in this dictionary?

1. https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nacido - born
2. https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nato - born
3. https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nado - to be swimming??

Does the asterisk means that i can use these 3 words interchangeably if i want to say "will be born"?

[image]

Comment: No sé si habrá peor forma de conjugar el verbo nacer. ¡Por favor!: ¿nos habremos nacido? ¿En serio? ¿Y este programa ---ABBYY--- es de pago? ¡Espero que no, porque es de risa... por no decir otra cosa.

Comment: Por cierto, @srghma, la conjugación del verbo **nacer** la tienes en https://dle.rae.es/nacer?m=form#conjugacionfnCcpea.

Comment: What is your point? That program is ridiculous.

Comment: This ridiculous conjugation seems dangerously widespread:
(1) https://www.larousse.fr/conjugaison/espagnol/nacerse/10001585
(2) https://www.conjugare.ro/spaniola.php?conjugare=nacerse
(3) https://www.scholingua.com/de/es/konjugation/nacerse
(4) https://www.bomespanhol.com.br/conjugar/verbo/nacerse

Comment: @aerobiomat I never said *nado, *nato was wrong. I am saying that trying to understand the question as written in that program is ridiculous. There was no need for that page at all. Pages like that should be discouraged here. Also, the OP could have looked this up in any good dictionary.

Comment: @karloswitt `nos habremos nacido` what's wrong with it? I see in https://www.conjugacion.es/del/verbo/nacer.php in `Futuro perfecto` it's `nosotros habremos nacido` too

Answer (score 2):

**Cuestión** : *What does the *nato, *nado means?*

El asterisco * significa, que teóricamente podrías utilizar tanto la palabra nacido, como nato ó nado, pero este es uno de los muchos errores que tiene la página, pues han tomado nato y nato, como nacido, pero esto no existe. Solo existe en un mal traductor.

The asterisk * means that theoretically you could use both the word born (nacido), such as nato or nado, but this is one of the many errors that the page has, since they have taken born and born, as born (nacido), but this does not exist. It only exists in a bad translator.

No estoy seguro de entender, pido perdón por si la respuesta no se corresponde, pero los datos son escasos.

Vamos a ver, para empezar esa página esta mal.
*That page is wrong*

1. Te da la definición de varias acepciones de "nacer".

*1) It gives you the definition of various meanings of "born".*

2. Te da una definición de nacer más resumida con tres acepciones.

*2) It gives you a more summarized definition of being born with three meanings.*

3. Te pone textos como ejemplos, pero en la gran mayoría no aparece el verbo nacer, sino el adverbio "nada".

*3) he gives you texts as examples, but in the vast majority the verb to be born does not appear, but rather the adverb "nothing" (nada).*

---

Como verbo reflexivo (nacerse), cambia de significado, en esta conjugación esta referida a una tela que se rompe.

As a reflexive verb (to be born), change the meaning, in this conjugation it refers to a fabric that breaks.

(nacerse)
Abrirse o deshilacharse [una tela o una prenda] por las costuras que tienen un borde escaso.
(be born)
To open or fray [a fabric or a garment] at seams that have a poor edge.

Aunque el verbo nacer  habitualmente no se utiliza de forma reflexiva (ser nacido) .

Although the verb to be born is not usually used reflexively, to (be born)

---

Ejem. Yo me nacía, significa, - Me abrí la costura

Ejem. Tu te nacías, significa - Tu te abriste la costuras

*Ejem. I was born, it means, - I opened the seam*

*Ejem. You were born, it means - You opened the seams*

---

La verdadera conjugación del verbo nacer la puedes encontrar aquí
*The true conjugation of the verb to be born can be found here*

**NACER** del latín natus "nacido".
*Verbo intransitivo. Dicho de un ser vivo : Salir del vientre materno , del huevo o de la semilla*

- https://www.conjugacion.es/del/verbo/nacer.php

**Presente**

yo nazco

tú naces

él nace

nosotros nacemos

vosotros nacéis

ellos nacen

---

**Pretérito imperfecto**

yo nacía

tú nacías

él nacía

nosotros nacíamos

vosotros nacíais

ellos nacían

etc...

..........

- Consejo, Encuentra ó buscas otro sitio mejor.

*Tip, Find another better site*

Comment: [what does x mean?] We really should correct the question in English first. Don't you think?

Comment: Updated a question

Comment: Still don't understand the meaning at asterisk

Comment: I like this dictionary bc it has so many conjugations

Comment: In this case, the asterisk *, is useless. En este caso, el asterisco *, no sirve para nada.

Answer (score 0):

In Spanish, the form that you are searching is "nací", cause in this language the pronoum is implicit, and it's not necessary to speak/write it.

So if you want to say "Yo nací", in practice you say "Nací".

You have the complete verb conjugation at [dle.rae.es/nacer?m=form#conjugacionfnCcpea](https://dle.rae.es/nacer?m=form#conjugacionfnCcpea).

Comment: How do you know what the OP wants??

Comment: Cause if you launch the OP link in a web browser:
https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/es-ru/Nac%C3%AD

the browser itself take and translate internally to 
https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/es-ru/Nací

Comment: This is beyond me and our scope here. Plus, it's all in Russian.

Comment: I cannot understand the downvote for my answer, cause I am answering to the OP question: "Nací".

Comment: Launch the link in a browser, and look top left of the page. Don't you see "Nací"?

Comment: The OP says: What the *nato, *nado means? [sic]. So, we do not know what form he or she is searching for. The question as asked makes no sense.

Comment: Like you, I see that the question, as it stands, is not very logical. But since he included the link, I tried to shed some light.

Comment: Ok, I just get annoyed when posters don't try and follow site rules and post a bunch of you-know-what. :)

Comment: Yes, the form didn't matter, i just wanted to know what the words with asterisk means in this dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have edited your question, the issue is something else.

> Does the asterisk means that i can use these 3 words interchangeably if i want to say "will be born"?

the answer is "No". You can't interchange these 3 words to say "(I) will be born", because the translation of this phrase is "Naceré". That’s is how I can see your question:

> https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nacido - born

born --> "nacido" --> action in the past

> https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nato - born

born --> "nato" --> action in the past

> https://www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/es-en/nado - to be swimming??

to be swimming --> "nado" --> action in the present, of the verb swim (=nadar), other than born (=nacer)